# Flutter go router. No extra parameter available for TypedGoRoute

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

Probably missing something but our project uses TypedGoRoutes so I have something like:

```
TypedGoRoute<MyScreenRoute>(path: 'my_route_name')
```

and then:

```
 class MyScreenRoute extends GoRouteData {

  const MyScreenRoute({
    this.initialValue = 0,
  });

  final int initialValue;
  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context, final GoRouterState state) =>
      MyScreen(
        models: state.extra! as List<MyCustomClass>,
        initialValue: initialValue,
      );
}
```

Calling this from a widget with:

```
const MyScreenRoute(initialValue: 5).push<void>(context);
```

Passing primitive values like the initialValue works fine but how can I pass the extra parameter? Looking at the generated code for .go and .push, there is only the location and queryParams (for the initialValue) but nothing for extra.

How can I get codegen also for the *extra* parameter for my MyScreenRoute so that I can do:

```
const MyScreenRoute(initialValue: 5).push<void>(context, myListOfCustomObjects);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: define the extra object with the name `$extra` in `MyScreenRoute`. 
check out https://pub.dev/packages/go_router_builder#extra-parameter

Comment: Thank you @Charles I had completely missed that in the docs. Will give it a try.